# How to display a error message with hyperlink on standard detail page through trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, hyperlink, adderror

I'm trying to add the record link inside the "addError" on the trigger

```
for(Account account : (List<Account>) triggerParams.triggerNew) {
      String url = URL.getOrgDomainUrl()+'/'+account.Id;
    account.addError('ERROR:<a href=\''+url+'\'>More details</a>', false);
}
```

But the result is this

```
ERROR:<a href='Url:[delegate=https://myOrg.com]/0016w000007aC6fAAE'>More details</a>
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

The getOrgDomainUrl method returns a [Url](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_url.htm#apex_methods_system_url). You need to convert it to a string via toExternalForm:

```
  String url = URL.getOrgDomainUrl().toExternalForm()+'/'+account.Id;
```

Comment: I'm using toecternalform, but it still doesn't seem like the <a> tag is recognized and interpreted as markup. The string is shown literally.

Comment: @Schnaps HTML errors are not supported in Lightning Experience. If you are still using classic, you can use the `addError(message, escape)` version of the method to specify the HTML should be shown literally. This answer only addresses why the URL appeared incorrectly. [See docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_addError_2)

Comment: That's what I was afraid to hear. The way I searched I just wasn't able to get confirmation on that.